# How to change content in variable based on pwd in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, node-modules

I would like to do following:

1. get all dependencies (dir names)
2. get basename of current directory
3. since current directory is not a dependency, get rid of it
4. print them

what I have so far (from `bashrc`):

```
export dep=$({ tmp=$(ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules/); echo ${tmp//$(basename $(pwd))/}; })
```

The goal is it to have it in variable, not a function or alias becuase I want to use it later (such as for `npm link $dep`), which I would not be able if it was function.

But the current output DOES include the current directory. Was it invoked from the current dir, the current dir would not be included. So I guess the variable is not reexecuted to take into account it changed its dir (from where bashrc is, to where I am now).

So how to make it to NOT include the current dir?

Comment: `which I would not be able if it was function` : You can do: `npm link $(fndep)` with a function

Comment: Tangentially, unless you have a tool which requires `dep` to be visible in its environment when it runs, the `export` is unnecessary here.

Comment: @anubhava well yes, but still be better as variable as variable is more versatile

Comment: Also tangentially, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Your code could be refactored to `( cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules; printf '%s\n' * )`

Comment: Huh? A static variable is _less_ versatile than a function you call dynamically when you need to.

Comment: @milanHrabos: You have to make a decision based on your requirement of static or dynamic? Moment you think of a dynamic value you have to use function

Comment: But in this case, the variable is made from dynamic calls `$(...)`, so I would expect that it would consequently have dynamic behaviour. I don't know, if that is the reason why it does not work.

Comment: The variable simply contains static text which gets evaluated at the time you assign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable is simply static text, the shell (or, let alone, the string itself) in no way keeps track of how its value was calculated; it's just a sequence of characters. If you need the value to change depending on external circumstances, you need to assign it again in those circumstances, or simply use a script or a function instead of a variable.

Here is a simple function which [avoids trying to parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
getdep () {
    ( cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules
      printf '%s\n' * ) |
    grep -vFx "$(basename "$(pwd)")"
}
```

You would call it like

```
dep=$(getdep)
```

when you need to update `dep`, or simply use `$(getdep)` instead of `$dep`.

Comment: Well I used `dep(){ find $node_modules -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f " | sed "s/$(basename $(pwd))//"; }`, but got the same result

Comment: The difference is mainly that you will get mangled entries for any module whose name contains the current directory. If your current directory is `foo` and you have a dependency `foobar`, it will be printed as `bar`, which is obviously a bug. `find` is much heavier than `printf` but functionally the two are equivalent, and `find` offers many options if you need something more complicated than just a simple list. (So, for example, `find ... -not -name "$(basename $(pwd))" -printf ...` would avoid the (buggy) `sed`.

Comment: The lack of quoting is also a bug; see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: I decided to use the version of `find` where negating the basename. Find seems to me more elegant then changing directories.